# jQuery and MouseEvents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I have a question regarding mouse events in the jQuery library.
I have a simple javascript function as following:

```
$(function() {
    var xpos;
    var ypos;
    $("#pic1").mousedown(function() {
        $("#pic1").mousemove(function(e) {
            xpos = e.pageX;
            ypos = e.pageY;
            $("#pic1").css({'left': xpos, 'top': ypos});
        });
    });
});
```

It makes it so you can click an image and it follows the mouse around. I'm trying to make it stop following by using the mouseup function, but it seems like it can't break the "repaint" method, where it updates the css coordinates.

HTML:

```
<img id="pic1" src="img/test.jpg" alt="">
```

CSS:

```
#pic1 {
position: absolute;
}
```

Would there be an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Adding an event handler inside another event handler, as you're doing, is almost never a good idea. Every time a "mousedown" event happens, you're adding another "mousemove" handler.

Comment: @Pointy I agree, though in this case, what he's doing may be valid... so long as he removes the `mousemove` handler in a `mouseup` handler.

Comment: Yeah, the plan was to make it follow when your mouse was pressed, and released when you let go.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've set this up the mousemove trigger is bound on mouse down.  To drop the element you would need to either unbind the trigger  (http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or set up a condition in the move handler so that the element's position is only updated if a condition is met and then make sure that mouse down/up turn that condition on/off.  The former seems simpler but even simpler might be to use the jquery ui: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the jquery ui draggable, your structure would look something like this:

```
$(function() {        
    $("#pic1").on('mousedown', function() {
        $(this).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            $(this).css({'left': e.pageX, 'top': e.pageY});
        });
    }).on('mouseup', function() {
        $(this).off('mousemove');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work sort of. I think I can work from this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little refactor using jQuery `.on()` and `.off()`:

```
$(function() {
    var xpos,
        ypos,
        $pic = $('#pic1');

    $pic.on('mousedown', function() {
        $pic.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            xpos = e.pageX;
            ypos = e.pageY;
            $pic.css({'left': xpos, 'top': ypos});
        });
    });

    $pic.on('mouseup',function(){
        $pic.off('mousemove');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tYpKL/1/

`.off()` is a pretty useful method that allows you to unbind methods set with `.on()`.

I think you should consider using a library to handle this functionality because, as you can tell from the demo, you aren't even close to a solid user-experience. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! Didn't know about the .on(), .off() feature

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier solution.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <style>
         #pic1 { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 1px; }
     </style>
     <script>
         $(function() {
             $("#pic1").draggable();
         });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pic1" class="ui-widget-content">
        <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link (http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) that will explain all the details of the API used for the draggable function.

Comment: I updated this for you above, by editing the original correspondence.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the jQuery UI as you mentioned. It made everything much easier!